# How to represent cell in libreoffice calc like B(2+4)?

Tags: average, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I need to do something in LibreOffice calc, but it depends on the number of the cell, so I would like to do something like this to represent the cell **=AVERAGE(B(0x4+1):(1x4))**, but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: I understand that by `B(0x4+1):(1x4)` you meant a range of cells, but I can't read your entry, I don't see the point in it. Did you want to write about range `B1:B4`? *like B(2+4)*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `INDIRECT` to get a cell reference or range reference from text.

For example put this into A1:

```
=AVERAGE(INDIRECT("B"&(4*(ROW(A1)-1)+1)&":"&"B"&(4*ROW(A1))))
```

Here I use the row number as the value for your `0` and `1`, respectively.

- `ROW(A1)` returns 1
- `"B"&(4*(ROW(A1)-1)+1)` returns `"B1"`
- `"B"&(4*ROW(A1))` returns `"B4"`
- Both concatenated together with `":"` in the middle returns `"B1:B4"`
- If you have `A2` instead of `A1`, the text will result in `"B5:B8"`

If you copy this formula into A2 and following as many times as you see fit, you will get your averages.

*Disclaimer: I tried this with a non-English version of LibreOffice 7.1 and translated the function names. They might be wrong.*

Comment: Good! Please take the [tour] to learn more how StackOverflow works. Then come back and mark this answer, please. Have a lot of fun!